# Нахождение названия сервера DIscord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Я разрабатываю бота на Discord.py. Хочу понять, как написать функцию, которая сама будет определять название сервера, на котором находится бот.

Answer (score 0):

В классе [Guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#guild), есть атрибут [name](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.name), который возвращает название сервера.

*Пример* 1:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot()


# Допустим у нас будет команда *name*
@bot.command()
async def name(ctx: commands.Context):
    # Получаем название сервера
    guild_name = ctx.guild.name
    # Что-то делаем дальше
    ...
```

*Пример* 2:

```
from discord import Guild
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot()


def get_guild_name(guild_id: int):
    # "Получаем" сервер
    guild: Guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
    # Название сервера
    guild_name = guild.name

    return guild_name
```